# What's the proper method of replacing the crank shaft oil seal of a Honda Rebel?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, oil-leak

I've been searching for a guide, but haven't found anything the deals with the oil seals specifically.

My '09 Honda Rebel is leaking oil into the flywheel cover, and I suspect the flywheel and crank shaft oil seals are to blame. It's been suggested that as long as I can pull the flywheel off, I should be able to remove the crank case oil seal with a pick tool and push the new one in. Is this true? What other steps or gotchas should I be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for full size engines so I don't see why you couldn't do it with a motorcycle. As long as you have access to the crankshaft.

1) Use a seal puller
2) Find a big socket or piece of pipe to put over the new seal to press it in.
3) Put oil on seal/shaft before re installing pulley/sprocket back over crankshaft.

Video on a car [here](http://youtu.be/fkmFa9KFDoA?t=2m34s)

Comment: Wow that channel looks unbelievably helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The Rebel seal pops out due to too much blow by pressure. You do not use a puller. You use the 16 millimeter bolt with the 1.5 pitch to remove the flywheel. Screw the bolt in. Tap the bolt. If the flywheel doesn't remove, screw the bolt in again. Tap the bolt. Rinse lather repeat - at some point the flywheel will spring loose.